# Как найти дубликаты Bitmap в списке объектов?

Tags: java, android

Есть большой массив объектов Bitmap. Нужно пройтись по каждому элементу и создать отдельный список где каждый дубликат будет отсортирован. Например, три одинаковых bitmap будет идти в порядке очереди, даже если последний дубликат был в конце списка.

Для сравнения используется метод Bitmap.sameAs(anotherBitmap).

Как можно перебрать массив таким образом, чтобы были минимальные временные затраты.

Comment: Не пробовали просто отсортировать? Должно и так сработать

Comment: большой массив битмап угробит трое приложение. Для определения уникальности твоих  снимков попробуй OpenCV